# Android Beacon Library - How to prevent any ScanJob to run while app is in foreground?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, beacon, altbeacon

I've an app that uses to the android-beacon-library to detect when the smartphone enters in range of some Beacons. After opening the app for the first time and initializing the `RegionBootstrap`, I noticed that `org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob` are run by the lib. This seems to cause delays with the app's main Bluetooth scanner, which runs only when the app is in foreground.

Therefore, I'd like the Beacon lib to scan for beacons only when the app is in background, or closed.

What is the best way for implementing this behavior please ?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1. Be sure to use BackgroundPowerSaver
2. Set beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(Long.MaxLong)

The above will make it so library scanning never happens when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: After trying this, I can see in the logs that ScanJob is running while the app is in foreground: I/ScanJob: Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@d07e272 I/ScanJob: Scan job running for 300000 millis

Comment: A scan will run briefly in the foreground for whatever you have setForegroundScanPeriod(..) to (1100 ms by default).  If you want to reduce this further, you can make it 0ms.  The ScanJob will still run, but it won't do anything, and will exit quickly.   This is admittedly inelegant, but the library wasn't designed for background-only use with it being disabled in the foreground, so some kludginess is needed to force that to happen.

Comment: I did try beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(0); but in the logs, I still see many "CycledLeScannerForLollipop: got record " and "got a filtered scan result in the background" as if the Beacon scanner is still active while the app is in foreground

Comment: Are you sure you are using BackgroundPowerSaver? That module should automatically set and clear foreground/background mode inside the library.  The fact that you see "got a filtered scan result in the background"  when your app is in the foreground suggests this isn't working.  For the purposes of this discussion "background" means the screen is not illuminated or none of the app's activities/fragments are visible on the screen.

Comment: Yes I do use BackgroundPowerSaver. In fact the foreground scan is eventually deactivated, but several seconds after app launch. Before that, I see "CycledLeScanner: Scan started" followed by many "CycledLeScannerForLollipop: got record." Also, I have to do beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false); to see background scans. I have the same behavior with the Reference app.

Comment: You may wish to try an alternative approach where you stop using `BackgroundPowerSaver` (thus leaving the library always in foreground mode, stop using `RegionBootstrap`, and instead programmatically call `beaconManager.bind(...)` and start ranging/monitoring when you app goes to the background, then reverse the process when the app goes to the foreground: stop ranging/monitoring, then call `beaconManager.unbind(...)`   But be aware that Android scanning APIs are asynchronous.  Stopping scanning will never be instantaneous.

Comment: I didn't know `beaconManager.bind(...)` could be used to run background scan also. I'll try calling it in my app's `onAppBackgrounded()` and calling `beaconManager.unbind(...)` in `onAppForegrounded()`. Many thanks for your help !